# how can i implement this for loop in java

Tags: java, android

```
package sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SectionListView extends ListActivity {

    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            mAdapter.addItem("Row Enter #" + i);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Group #" + i);
            }
        }
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


}
```

how can edit this for loop to have this out put

```
#1 normal for loop
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

```
#2 advance for loop
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between expected and actual output? The lines with the hash mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SectionListView extends ListActivity {

    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        fillList();
        fillAdapter(mAdapter);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void fillList(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //this will alternate between "normal" and "advance"
            list.add(i % 2 == 0 ? "normal" : "advance");

            list.add("Text");
            list.add("Text.");
            list.add("Text..");
        }
    }

    private void fillAdapter(CustomAdapter adapter) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int row = i % 3;

            if (row == 0) {
                adapter.addSectionHeaderItem(list.get(i) + (i + 1));
                continue;
            }

            adapter.addItem(list.get(i) + (row + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it working but how to can change these  Group #1 text 1 text 2 to real names like peter  john etc

Comment: should it be 30 loops, is it one list for the rows ( or multiple lists of 3 items) is it an alternating naming for the groups or where are the names coming from?

Comment: it not a must it be a 30 loops but i just need different 4 items each(multiple lists of like 4 items)

Comment: Thanks for your commitment i am happy for that reach me on hangouts or watsup kanaaaa.ft@gmail.com +254725959830

Comment: i dont have neither hangout nor whatsapp but if you have any other question please feel free to ask it here it would be better so other can also see your question and learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
            int value = i % 3;
            if (value == 0) {
                mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Group #" + (i+1));
            }
            mAdapter.addItem("Row Enter #" + (value + 1));
        }
```

> "It now working how can i edit these row enter#1 to names where by the
>   groups are having different names .here i mean that the names i group
>   one should not be in group two ..thanks in advance as u help"

You can do this way then :

```
class Group {
  String name;
  String members[];

  public Group(String name, String [] members) {
    this.name = name;
    this.members = members;
  }
}
```

In your onCreate() :

```
ArrayList<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
groups.add(new Group("Group A", new String[]{"A","B","C"}));
groups.add(new Group("Group B", new String[]{"A","B","C"}));
groups.add(new Group("Group C", new String[]{"A","B","C"}));
groups.add(new Group("Group D", new String[]{"A","B","C"}));
groups.add(new Group("Group F", new String[]{"A","B","C"}));

mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
for(Group group : groups) {
    mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem(group.name);
    for (int i = 0; i < group.members.length; i ++) {
        mAdapter.addItem(group.members[i]);
    }
}
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: it now displaying anything please  how can i make it to display different text eg first group1 (john) (peter) group 2  mary francis etc.

Comment: i have two java files but this one is the one to output

Comment: It now working how can i edit these row enter#1 to names where by the groups are having different names .here i mean that the names i group one should not be in group two ..thanks in advance as u help

Comment: @FrancisNdirangu, I have updated my answer, please check , or you can use HashMap as well, where key will be your group name and values can be your members list.

Comment: Thank you ..i am soo happy for your help please i just wonna chat more my email is Kanaaaa.ft@gmail.com add me on your Hangouts or watsup i am currently young in android and i want to grow big like you +254725959830